# How to open a link in the current window by pressing a button in Google App Script UIApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a script that allows a user to log in to the site.  I have everything done but I can't seem to find a way to open a new link after the user has been authenticated by pressing the log in button.

Steps:

1. User enter username and password
2. The user is authenticated
3. If the user exists in the spreadsheet a link is opened to the user's profile (this is the link I can't seem to get working).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example : type one of the names, if 3 letters are correct then the link appears

```
function showDialog() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("AnchorTest");
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var txtBox = app.createTextBox().setName("tbox");
  var subm = app.createAnchor('OK', 'href').setId('subm').setVisible(false);
  var fake = app.createButton('Enter your lastName').setId('fake');
  panel.add(txtBox).add(subm).add(fake);
  var keyHandler = app.createServerHandler("textkey");
  txtBox.addKeyUpHandler(keyHandler);
  keyHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  var clickHandler = app.createServerHandler("showurl");
  subm.addClickHandler(clickHandler)
  clickHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
//
function textkey(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var href = app.getElementById('subm');
  var fake = app.getElementById('fake');
  href.setVisible(false);
  fake.setVisible(true);
  var txtValue = e.parameter.tbox;
  var data=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    Logger.log(data)
    Logger.log(txtValue.length);
    if (txtValue.length>2){
      for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
        Logger.log(txtValue+'  '+data[nn][0])
          if(data[nn][0].match(txtValue)==txtValue){
          href.setHref(data[nn][1]).setHTML('ACCEPTED').setVisible(true);
          fake.setVisible(false);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
return app;  
}
//  
function showurl(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;  
}
```

Here are data available in the corresponding sheet (column A & B)

```
> lastName  url
> serge https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home
> john  https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/a-database-project
> paul  https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/a-simple-search-tool-ui
> mike  https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/doc-list-viewer
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand now.  I will try to find a way to make this work but just to be sure, is there no function similar to JavaScript's windows.open() that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [anchor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_anchor?hl=fr-FR), I think it does what you are looking for doesn't it ? you could make it visible once the user has been authenticated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I've been looking at anchor but I can't seem to find a method that works with it.  Would it be possible to provide an example?

Comment: [This script is a Doc list viewer](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/doc-list-viewer) that shows the content of your Google docs folder, when you select a doc it show a link to open it using an anchor widget

Comment: Thank you for your help.  If I've missed something I apologize but I do not need a clickable link but rather something that redirects the user from the current page to a new one within a function.  In JavaScript I would have used something like windows.open('www.site.com', '_self', false).

Comment: You could 'disguise' the anchor into a button and use it like a 'submit' or 'validate' since you can add a lot of different handlers to this widget (mouseUp, mouseDown...) so when user presses the button to validate his sign-in he opens the target url.

Comment: To be more explicit : Google Apps Script cannot interact directly with your browser since it's a server-side application but this is, I guess, a possible workaround.

Comment: That's what I want to but how would I go about coding that in the click event handler?

Comment: see answer, comments are becoming too long